# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execCommand')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

I'm making a text editor in React and ran into a problem with using the "execCommand" command problem: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execCommand')". How can I fix it?

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. Perhaps the problem is due to the fact that I use iframes. Perhaps the Edit function is better called in the button component. But so far I've settled on this variant, which doesn't work.

```js
import classNames from "classnames";
import styles from "./MainNoteButton.module.css"
import React, {useEffect} from "react"

function MainNoteButton(props, { buttonFunction }) {

    return (
        <button onclick={buttonFunction} class={styles.action_button}><img src={props.buttondata.icon} alt="" className={styles.action_icon}/></button>
    )
}

export default MainNoteButton;
```

```js
function NotesPage() {
    const [icons] = useState([
        {id:1, buttonFunction: "'bold'", icon: bold},
        {id:2, buttonFunction: "'italic'", icon: italic},
        {id:3, buttonFunction: "'underline'", icon: underline},
        {id:4, buttonFunction: "'strikeThrough'", icon: strikethrough},
        {id:5, buttonFunction: "'justifyLeft'", icon: align_left},
        {id:6, buttonFunction: "'justifyCenter'", icon: center},
        {id:7, buttonFunction: "'justifyFull'", icon: justify_full},
        {id:8, buttonFunction: "'cut'", icon: cut},
        {id:9, buttonFunction: "'subscript'", icon: subscript},
        {id:10, buttonFunction: "'superscript'", icon: superscript},
        {id:11, buttonFunction: "'undo'", icon: undo},
        {id:12, buttonFunction: "'redo'", icon: redo},
        {id:13, buttonFunction: "'insertUnorderedList'", icon: list},
        {id:14, buttonFunction: "'insertOrderedList'", icon: number_list},
    ])

    const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState(true)

    const toggleOpen = () => {
        setOpenMenu(!openMenu)
    }

    function enableEditMode() {
        const textpart = document.getElementsByName('textPart')[0];
        const iframeDocument= textpart.contentDocument || textpart.contentWindow.document;
        iframeDocument.designMode = "on";
    }

    const iFrameDoc = useRef()

    function Edit(command) {
        iFrameDoc.current.document.execCommand(command, false, null);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.onload = enableEditMode();
    }, [])



    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.nav_menu}>
                <div className={`${styles["menu"]} ${!openMenu ? styles.menu_active : ""}` }>
                    <div className={styles.buttons_block}>
                        {icons.map(icon => <div ><MainNoteButton buttondata={icon} key={icon.id} /></div>)}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.open_menu_button_block}>
                    <div onClick={toggleOpen} className={styles.open_menu_button}>
                        <img src={arrow_down} className={`${styles["arrow_down"]} ${!openMenu ? styles.button_active : ""}`} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={Edit('bold')}>sss</button>
            <iframe ref={iFrameDoc} name={"textPart"} className={styles.text_space} style={{frameborder: 0}}>
            </iframe>
        </>
    )
}

export default NotesPage;
```

Comment: Did you mean to use [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) instead of `document` on the iframe?

Answer (score 1):

When you define `onClick` like this - `onClick={Edit('bold')}`, it invokes the function immediately and therefore your `ref` is undefined. You should pass it as a callback to the onClick function like this:

```
<button onClick={() => Edit('bold')}>sss</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped, but nothing happens when you click the button, i.e. execCommand does not work